# How to classify error types in javascript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am trying to produce a more child-friendly translation of the errors in JS. For example:

```
const errorTranslate = (error) => {
  let hint;
  switch (error) {
    case "Unexpected identifier" :
      hint = "Parece que hay un error de sintaxis en tu código. Verificá que no hayan declaraciones de variables mal definidas o asignaciones a variables mal escritas."
      break;
    default: hint=error;
  }
  return hint;
}
```

Is there a list of error categories that match any attribute of the err object?

Comment: I think these may be implementation-specific. They might even be localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are punch of error types

For example:

- Error.
- EvalError.
- InternalError.
- RangeError.
- ReferenceError.
- SyntaxError.
- TypeError.
- URIError.

Every error has a special error `message`.

You can check if the `error` is one of these by `instanceof` as all these types `extend` from the `Error` type.

```
const errorTranslate = (error) => {
let hint;
if (error instanceof ReferenceError) {
      hint = "Parece que hay un error de sintaxis en tu código. Verificá que no hayan declaraciones de variables mal definidas o asignaciones a variables mal escritas."
  } else {
     hint=error.message
}
  return hint;
}
```

More information about error handing, you can check this article.

https://www.valentinog.com/blog/error/

Comment: `error` can never match a boolean `case`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it should be `if` instead of `switch`, just update the answer.